# Extract files matching pattern from RAR archive

Tags: command-line, regex, winrar

I have an RAR archive,
and I want to extract all files with a three-digit number as an extension.
I tried with Winrar but it does not accept REGular EXpression:

```
winrar.exe e -y pinetinf pinet.[0-9*] .      // pattern: does not work
winrar.exe e -y pinetinf pinet.222 .         // single file name: WORK
```

How can I extract all the files whose names have a three-digit extension?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't.

Comment: I think you can use `list` option of `rar` (or you can use 7-zip that can also extract files form rar) then bypass result to some filter (some external tool that will extract filenames you need without PITA) then extract files using `include` options of archiver together with extract option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using WinRAR only but you can call Powershell to help you out with the filtering.

List the files from the archive and pipe the output to a for loop to extract the needed ones in a Powershell console.

```
& 'UnRAR.exe' 'lb' '.\file.rar' | ForEach-Object { If($_ -like '*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]') { & 'UnRAR.exe' 'e' '.\file.rar' $_ } }
```

Alternatively you can create a list file and run unrar.exe only once to extract the files (maybe it's a bit faster to do it this way if you have loads of files).

```
& 'UnRAR.exe' 'lb' '.\file.rar' | ForEach-Object { If($_ -like '*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]') { Out-File '.\files.list' -InputObject $_ -Append } } | & 'UnRAR.exe' 'e' '.\file.rar' '-n@.\files.list'
```